# on press enter perform next button action in EXTJS

Tags: extjs

I have create the wizard in extjs. in the forms i have 2 fields, I need when user fill the last textfield the press <kbd>Enter</kbd> the action should be perform as user cliking on next button. how to achieve it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
{
    xtype:'textfield',
    name:'whatever',
    enableKeyEvents: true,
    listeners: {
        keypress : function(textfield,eo){
            if (eo.getCharCode() == Ext.EventObject.ENTER) {
                //enter is pressed call the next buttons handler function here.
                this.up('form').down('nextButton').handler
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i would amend the answer to the more precise version:

`textfield.nextSibling().handler();`

this would call the handler of anything standing next to the field (ie, a button)

Answer (score 1):

Or you can define the function's name directly:

If your button was created like this:

```
xtype: 'button',
text : 'Go',
listeners: {
    click: {
        fn: me.onSearchClick,
        scope: me
    }
}
```

You can do this:

```
{ 
    xtype:'textfield',
    name:'whatever',
    enableKeyEvents: true,
    listeners: {
        keypress : function(textfield,eventObject){
            if (eventObject.getCharCode() == Ext.EventObject.ENTER) {
                me.onSearchClick();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I achieved this is different to the above, answers, and in my opinion it is superior as you can use the proper MVC model rather than doing it in the view as you have seen.

Within my controller I used the following code in the event definitions (which we do within the init function):

```
'searchform textfield': {
    specialkey: this.specialKeyPress
},
```

where 'searhform' is the selector defined in the controller for the form.

Then, the function that handles this looks like the below:

```
/**
*   Peform the serach when the enter key is pressed.
*/
specialKeyPress(f, e, o) {
    if(e.getKey() == e.ENTER) {
        this.performSearch();
    }
},
```

The added advantage of this, is that it works on all text fields by default, rather than having to add it manually to each one.